# jsonify list of dictionaries and send as response from ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, flask

I am currently trying to request data from my server. I use flask, and my response-function which is taking data from a db and translates it to a list of dictionaries that later is jsonified, looks like this:

```
@app.route('/database/customer/<int:customer_id>/', methods=['GET'])
def customer_id(customer_id):
    c, conn = connectionCust()
    computerdb = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Computers WHERE customer_id=(%s)", customer_id)
    computerdb = c.fetchall()

    computerList = []
    for computer in computerdb:
        computerDict = {
            'computer_id': str(computer[0]).strip('L'),
            'computer_name': computer[2]}
        computerList.append(computerDict)

    return jsonify(computerList)
```

If I enter e.g. http://0.0.0.0:8080/database/customer/3
it displays

```
[
  {
    "computer_id": "5", 
    "computer_name": "CUST3COMP1"
  }, 
  {
    "computer_id": "6", 
    "computer_name": "CUST3COMP2"
  }, 
  {
    "computer_id": "7", 
    "computer_name": "CUST3COMP3"
  }
]
```

My ajax code, which is connected to a dropdown, says:

```
$('#customer').chosen().change(function(event){
                if(event.target == this){
                    $.ajax({ 
                       type: "GET",
                       dataType: "jsonp",
                       url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/database/customer/" + $(this).val(),
                       success: function(data){        
                         alert(data);
                       }
                    });
                };
            });
```

But I can't alert the data which is sent back, when I look at the log, it says

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2016 13:02:06] "GET /database/customer/3?callback=jQuery112006497998475787305_1480507320739&_=1480507320740 HTTP/1.1" 301 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2016 13:02:06] "GET /database/customer/3/?callback=jQuery112006497998475787305_1480507320739&_=1480507320740 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I think it is something wrong with the jsonify() or maybe the ajax-code. You guys which are more familiar with these things maybe has some input on how I can access my response?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried **dataType: "json"** and also removing it? It may be that it is not a valid json. It is most probably jQuery problem not a flask one.

Comment: Seems to be no difference in my log if i have jsonp, json or nothing. Also still can't alert the data :/

Comment: Just to make sure try setting **async = false** and **dataType = text**, and again try changing **sucess** to **complete**.

Comment: even though i am using complete, i cant alert.. This is so weird..

Comment: update: i can now alert when i use complete, if i alert(data); i get a popup with [bject Object]

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: when i insert "error" and "success" it goes to error, like: `error: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));}` gives me an output of: **{"readyState":4,"responseText":"[{\"computer_id\":\"2\",\"computer_name\":\"CUST1COMP1\"},{\"computer_id\":\"8\",\"computer_name\":\"CUST1COMP2\"},{\"computer_id\":\"9\",\"computer_name\":\"CUST1COMP3\"}]\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}**

Comment: I changed **dataType: "jsonp"** to **dataType: "json"** and now it works, it didn't work before though, maybe i had something cached that was messing with me :) thanks for yout input!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a problem from the Flask side. Try changing your Ajax call dataType to **json** instead of jsonp and using **async=false** :

```
$('#customer').chosen().change(function(event){
            if(event.target == this){
                $.ajax({ 
                   type: "GET",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: false,
                   url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/database/customer/" + $(this).val(),

                   success: function(data){        
                     alert(data);
                   },
                   error: function(data) {
                     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                   }

                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: Problem is solved, answer is in the comments, just had to change to "json" (i think i didnt change anything else!)